# How to implement a parallel map in swift

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, parallel-processing

I have the following code:-

```
extension Collection {

    // EZSE : A parralelized map for collections, operation is non blocking
    public func pmap<R>(_ each: (Self.Iterator.Element) -> R) -> [R?] {
        let indices = indicesArray()
        var res = [R?](repeating: nil, count: indices.count)

        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: indices.count) { (index) in
            let elementIndex = indices[index]
            res[index] = each(self[elementIndex])
        }

        // Above code is non blocking so partial exec on most runs
        return res
    }

    /// EZSE : Helper method to get an array of collection indices
    private func indicesArray() -> [Self.Index] {
        var indicesArray: [Self.Index] = []
        var nextIndex = startIndex
        while nextIndex != endIndex {
            indicesArray.append(nextIndex)
            nextIndex = index(after: nextIndex)
        }
        return indicesArray
    }
}
```

In here at the return statement res, it often returns with part of the execution completed. Makes sense, concurrent Perform is non blocking. I am unsure how to proceed to wait for it. Should I use something like a dispatch group/expectations or is there some simpler more elegant method? Essentially I am looking for a simple wait notify abstraction in swift.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
// EZSE : A parralelized map for collections, operation is non blocking
public func pmap<R>(_ each: @escaping (Self.Iterator.Element) -> R) -> [R] {
    let totalCount = indices.count
    var res = ContiguousArray<R?>(repeating: nil, count: totalCount)
    
    let queue = OperationQueue()
    queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = totalCount
    
    let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
    indices
        .enumerated()
        .forEach { index, elementIndex in
            queue.addOperation {
                let temp = each(self[elementIndex])
                lock.lock()
                res[index] = temp
                lock.unlock()
            }
    }
    queue.waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished()
    
    return res.map({ $0! })
}
```

Comment: Why not return `[R]` instead of `[R?]` ? I tried forcing it with `res.map({ $0! })` and it crashed, which shouldn't be the case right?

Comment: @RodrigoRuiz, yep, can be rewritten to return `[R]`. And the crash you got: did it happen in the playground? 'cos i only could reproduce it in the playground, and if i add some random extra code(like `print`), using local `res` variable before `map` with `$0!` even in playground it works ok. I guess it's infamous playground memory management in action.

Comment: When I go to 10000 operations it crashes. Any idea why?

Comment: `return res.compactMap({$0})`

Comment: @UnchartedWorks, it would be safer, but may omit some element of original collection and mess up all indexes in the result array.

Comment: Causes crashes look at my answer. It accesses `res` in a thread save way.

Comment: @Hadus, modified by adding a recursive lock. Works the same as `DispatchQueue.sync`, but without extra wrapper over the functionality we need here.

Answer (score 7):

@user28434's answer is great and it can be made even faster by using `concurrentPerform`:

```
extension Collection {
    func parallelMap<R>(_ transform: @escaping (Element) -> R) -> [R] {
        var res: [R?] = .init(repeating: nil, count: count)

        let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: count) { i in
            let result = transform(self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)])
            lock.lock()
            res[i] = result
            lock.unlock()
        }

        return res.map({ $0! })
    }
}
```

It compares to using `OperationQueue()` on the task I'm running (running some function of mine on 10,000 items in parallel) Using 100 runs to average:

- `concurrentPerform` takes 0.060 seconds on average.
- `OperationQueue()` takes 0.087 seconds on average.

Comment: It's quite good, and even faster than mine . Only few notes: it should be `Collection` extension, not just `Array`.

Comment: @user28434 `NSRecursiveLock` is faster and nicer than what I used I will use it from now on 

Comment: The initial problem in the question states that concurrentPerform is nonblocking, so not everything is finished when you return. Wouldn't this have the same problem?

Comment: @AdamA I think the docs say that it waits: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2016088-concurrentperform This was a long time ago.. sorry I don't remember.

Comment: Yeah I tried it out myself and it definitely does wait, so not sure what was wrong with the OPs code!

Comment: You did add locking here which is cool if necessary. Being a newbie, I'm wondering what cases you'd need to lock if each thread is accessing a different index. I'm guessing it's only when growing capacity with append that you would need to lock but there are probably good reasons I'm wrong!

Comment: @AdamA Since we create `res` to be already the full length it won't reallocate. I really don't see a reason why locking there should be necessary. Yes for append you would need locking. I think the reason I had the lock there is because of @user28434's answer..