# Concurrent access to elements of Array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, concurrency, objective-c++

I try to write and read from Arrays (from different arrays) in Swift in concurrent way, and have exception in the runtime on write operation.
I have concurrent blur code in Objective-C++:

```
- (cpp_blur::Bitmap)blur {
    Bitmap result(_source);
    auto indexes = [[NSIndexSet alloc] initWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, _source.size())];
    int minIndex = 0;
    int maxIndex = static_cast<int>(result.size()) - 1;
    [indexes enumerateIndexesWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                              usingBlock:[&](NSUInteger idx, BOOL* _Nonnull stop){
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = static_cast<int>(idx) - static_cast<int>(self.radius); i <= idx + self.radius; i++) {
            int index = clamp(i, minIndex, maxIndex);
            sum += self->_source.at(index);
        }
        sum /= static_cast<double>(self.radius * 2 + 1);
        result.at(idx) = sum;
    }];

    return result;
}
```

I try to write same code in Swift:

```
@objc public func blur() -> [Double] {
        var result = source
        let indexSet = NSIndexSet(indexesIn: NSMakeRange(0, source.count))
        let from = -Int(self.blurRadius)
        let to = Int(self.blurRadius)
        let lastIndex = self.source.count - 1
        indexSet.enumerate(options: .concurrent) { (index:Int, _) in
            let sum = ((from + index)...(to + index)).reduce(0.0) { (partial:Double, nonClamped:Int) -> Double in
                let index = self.clamp(nonClamped, min: 0, max: lastIndex)
                let result = partial + self.source[index]
                return result
            }
            let avg = sum / Double(2 * self.blurRadius + 1);
            result[index] = avg //here I have crash in runtime
        }

        return result
    }
```

If I add a lock around `result[index] = avg`, this exception will move away, but I will have performance issue.
How I can change values of elements in Swift Array without lock (In same time I change only different elements)?
[Github repo.](https://github.com/K-Be/CompareSwift-and-CPP-concurrent-blur)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement a parallel map in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42619447/how-to-implement-a-parallel-map-in-swift)

Comment: No, doesn't there is problem with a waiting of completions all tasks. But in answers there, also added a lock around writing operation. I want to avoid a lock because I write into different indexes and have enough memory for it.

Comment: Locks are there to prevent racing condition on write in the array. You want that regardless if you have resources or not. And considering `waiting of completion`: `enumerateIndexesWithOptions` has it built-in. Without waiting your outer function will just return initial value of `result`. You gotta wait until stuff gets written synchronously.

Comment: enumerateIndexesWithOptions runs blocks concurrently (not async) (if was called with .concurrent option) and waits, while all blocks will complete.

Comment: If you change different indexes of array, you will never have racing condition because different elements should be independent. It is like to change different variables in different threads, may be in Swift, Arrays are more complicated objects, that controls access to elements and have some shared state for all elements in the array.

Comment: Yes, that's what I said. Also, you should remember that Objective C's `NSArray` is a **reference** type. Swift's `Array` is a **value** type (struct). Each time you put/add element to the array, essentially it creates a copy of array with applied changes. It's not thread safe operation. You **need** lock here.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=10

Comment: Also, *majority of implementations of collection types  in all languages are not thread safe on write*. You should never assume it's "like to change different variables in different threads". Unless you like to spend few nights debugging your crashing parallel code.

Comment: May be you are right, but I do not understand how to write blur that will have same (or near) performance in Swift. Because, if I add lock/unlock I will have performance issue.

Comment: If you are asking about `Blur` specifically: it should be done with [`GPU`/`simd`](http://ermig1979.github.io/Simd/help/group__other__filter.html) and not on `CPU` anyways. If you're asking in general: for desired performance you will have to manage memery manually using buffers and whatnot. But better look at `simd`.

Comment: GPU is not the best choice for a blur with radius 1000 (for example). A blur just example. Simd is very good library, but it is a C library, I can use (Accelarate)[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate] to make calculations, but it is also C-like way. It is questions about restrictions of Swift, and ways to avoid these restrictions in Swift.

Comment: "A blur just example" - with this mindset your question is too broad for SO, people have suggested the proper solution for blur operations, if you need something general then you should rephrase your question.